# How to use the phrase "尝一尝"?

Tags: meaning, usage, phrase

Recently I encountered the phrase "尝一尝" in a sentence. I need some advice on the way to use it and when to use it. And is 尝一尝 similar to 试一试?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some time and some environment, 尝一尝 is similar to 试一试.

Generally, when you want someone to try the taste of some food or experience with taste. They are the same meaning.

But sometimes when you want to try a car. You cannot say taste the car.

Answer (score 2):

**尝** basically means to taste something.

- 尝一尝 = to have a taste of something

Usually it is used quite literally, i.e.: to do with flavors and tastes of edibles.

Here is an example sentence from *New Century E-C*:

> 很多人出于习惯往食物里加盐, 都不先尝一尝。
>   Many people add salt to their food out of habit, without even tasting it first.

You can find a bunch of examples from TV show subtitles [here](https://www.91dub.com/search/%E5%B0%9D%E4%B8%80%E5%B0%9D?type=search):

> Yeah? Take a taste.
>   尝一尝

> you can taste it
>   你可以尝一尝

etc.

---

试 on the other hand means try.

- 试一试 = to have a try at something

Here is an example sentence from *New Century E-C*:

> 这有点儿不靠谱, 但我想我会试一试。
>   It's a bit far-fetched but I thought I would give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

尝一尝 literally means 'take a taste'

user3306356 already stated the difference between '尝一尝'(take a taste) and  '试一试' (take a try) in his answer.

However '尝一尝/ 一尝'(taste once = have a taste )  can also be used metaphorically for "to experience once/ to have an experience of"

Example:

尝一尝铁窗生涯 = have a taste of prison life / have an experience of prison life

尝一尝清闲之乐 = have a taste of leisure life / have an experience of leisure life

When 尝一尝 is used metaphorically for "to have an experience of", it is more common to omit the first 尝 and use '一尝' instead

一尝铁窗生涯

一尝清闲之乐

Note:

> '尝' (taste) itself is often used metaphorically for 'to experience'
>
> Example: 尝尽人间辛酸 - '**taste** the bitterness and sourness of life' = '**experience** the heartache of life'

Answer (score 2):

1、to have a taste of something

for example
①这个沙拉我能 尝一尝 吗？
②我做了烤牛排，你们来 尝一尝 味道怎么样。

2、exceptional case

让他尝一尝我拳头的厉害   =  打他，教训他